# How to turn marked text into footnote in word

Tags: microsoft-word, latex

I have a microsoft word file (originally from latex) that is littered with footnotes in between a `\footnote{}` tag. Here is an example

```
This is some text in MS word.\footnote{I would like to turn 
this into an MS footnote and delete the footnote tag.} Here is 
some more text in MS word.\footnote{Here is a second footnote.}
```

I can find each footnote by searching using regular expressions

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest investigating keyboard macros in MSWord. I don't have a copy of Word at hand but there is a way to record your keyboard actions and then replay them later.

You could, hypothetically, record a macro which cuts the selected text, opens the footer, inserts the text into a footnote, and then removes the `\footnote{}` surrounding it.

Then select the LaTeX footnote and replay the macro.

I apologize in advance that this is a hypothetical answer.